# Allow single user to edit at a time

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a large list that multiple people will be accessing and editing potentially at the same time. Is there any way to adjust settings to only allow a single site user to edit a particular list at a time?

Comment: Is this a simple list or a document library? Document libraries have a setting "Force check-out"...

Comment: Simple list. It could be a created custom list or an import from excel list.

Comment: This is exactly what the force check out feature is for, like @Evariste mentioned.

Comment: Is force check out only for document libraries, or can you enable it for custom lists?

Comment: You can configure it for generic list too.

Comment: One more question. Will the item checked out remain checked out indefinitely until checked back in?

Comment: I'm not finding the require check out option in a general list's settings. That option is only there for my document library.

Comment: Check in/out actions are based on SPFile object rather than SPlistItem, it’s only available on libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with standard functionality.